# php internal server not visible externally from amazon aws

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I am doing some testing on a server for which security is almost zero importance. For these tests I want to use a php server provided internally as of version 5.4.  However on amazon AWS the bound port is not accessible externally (hangs on connecting..):

```
$ php -S 10.138.XXX.XXX:81 -t ~/webapps/ssh
PHP 5.4.37 Development Server started at Fri Feb 20 23:22:12 2015
```

Now we are able to access the php server localy on that box:

```
wget 10.138.XXX.XXX:81/webconsole.php
```

But when attempting remote access the connection hangs/times-out

Here is the port that is only visible on localhost  - not externally:

```
$ netstat -an | grep 81  #81 is the php port number
tcp        0      0 10.138.xxx.xxx:YY             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
```

As a counter example let's look at the Jetty server port, which IS visible externally:

Here is a working - visible externally - port 8080:

```
root@ip-10-138-XXX-XXX ~]$ netstat -an | grep 8080
tcp        0      0 :::8080                     :::*                        LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::18080                    :::*                        LISTEN
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.138.xxx.xxx:8080    ::ffff:107.1.xxx.xxx:61428   ESTABLISHED
```

Comment: Looks like a firewall at AWS where you've added a rule to allow port 8080.  If not, maybe check your `iptables -n -L PREROUTING`.

Answer (score 0):

In the inbound rules of the security group that your instance belongs to, you can open port 81 inbound to your IP address or to everyone.